# Host Chef Server 12 on a purchased domain name

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I have installed **chef server** on **Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS EC2** and attached an **Elastic IP** to it. Then I mapped that IP to DNS host which I purchased.

If I access site using https://mydnsname.com, I get the chef server page and able to create organization and all.

I downloaded chef-starter package to my local system.

When I do **`$ knife ssl fetch`**, I got the following error message :

> Connecting to host mydnsname.com:443
>       ERROR: The SSL cert is signed by a trusted authority but is not valid for the given hostname
>       ERROR: You are attempting to connect to:   'mydnsname.com'
>       ERROR: The server's certificate belongs to 'ip-172-31-45-242.ec2.internal'*

**`$ knife ssl fetch`** gives

> WARNING: Certificates from mydnsname.com will be fetched and placed in your trusted_cert directory (~/chef/chef-repo/.chef/trusted_certs).
>       Knife has no means to verify these are the correct certificates. You should verify the authenticity of these certificates after downloading.                                                                                                                                                                                                               Adding certificate for ip-172-31-45-242.ec2.internal in ~/chef/chef-repo/.chef/trusted_certs/ip-172-31-45-242_ec2_internal.crt
>       I have generated self signed certificate for my domain name mydnsname.com and placed it on /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/ directory*

I have generated self signed certificate for my domain name mydnsname.com and placed it on `/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/` directory

But still I am not getting success.

my **/etc/hosts** file on server looks like

`127.0.0.1 mydnsname.com chef
127.0.0.1 localhost
54.173.215.55 mydnsname.com chef`

How can I configure chef server on AWS EC2 with a domain name and knife on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

There's some things to do for this.
The first one would be to define the name you use in `chef-server.rb` with the 
`api_fqdn` attribute as it drives nginx configuration.

Some doc [here](http://docs.chef.io/server/config_rb_server.html#recommended-settings) about the options of `chef-server.rb`

The doc is not exhaustive but you can check the attributes needed in the chef-server cookbooks used by `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`. The default values are in `/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/attributes/default.rb`  (or visible [here](https://github.com/chef/opscode-omnibus/blob/master/files/private-chef-cookbooks/private-chef/attributes/default.rb) just strip the first level attribute in the chef-server.rb file and use the next key as object).

i.e:

`default['private_chef']['nginx']['server_name'] = node['fqdn']` would be overridden in chef-server.rb by `nginx['server_name'] = "mydnsname.com"`

At end you can ensure you have the whole attributes ok before reconfigure with `chef-server-ctl show-config` which will print the values changed from default or computed for your server.

Comment: I have checked, my chef-server.rb is empty in Chef12.

There is a file /etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json which contains all the details. I have changed fqdn in that file, but no success

Comment: The chef-server.rb has to be created to define overriding values. The chef-server-running.json show the values for the running instance as its name implies.